# How can I decrease font size in LaTeX nomenclature using nomencl package?

Tags: fontsize, nomencl

I have used `nomencl` package to create my papers nomenclature. The problem, however, is that the font size is 12pt, which is very large and takes many pages for nomenclature.

How can I decrease the font size to 10pt in nomencl package? I couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `nomencl` package features. The macro `\nompreamble` is used at the start of the list (after having produced the title) and you can redefine it as you wish. By default it does nothing.

Here I used `\scriptsize` to show the effect, use `\small` or `\footnotesize` instead.

I reused some code I already had, with some more customizations which you're free to keep or discard.

```latex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols} %% may be this is good.
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\scriptsize} % just by way of example, use \small instead

\makenomenclature

% use this if you plan to have a nomenclature taking more than one page
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}
  {\chapter*{\nomname}}
  {\chapter*{\nomname}\markboth{\MakeUppercase\nomname}{\MakeUppercase\nomname}}
  {}{}
%%%%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoftables

\printnomenclature

\mainmatter % book mode only

\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction

\nomenclature[]{FOO1}{bar1}
\nomenclature[]{FOO2}{bar2}
\nomenclature[]{FOO3}{bar3}
\nomenclature[]{FOO4}{bar4}
\nomenclature[]{FOO5}{bar5}
\nomenclature[]{FOO6}{bar6}
\nomenclature[]{FOO7}{bar7}
\nomenclature[]{FOO8}{bar8}
\nomenclature[]{FOO9}{bar9}
\nomenclature[]{FOO10}{bar10}
\nomenclature[]{FOO11}{bar11}
\nomenclature[]{FOO12}{bar12}
\nomenclature[]{FOO13}{bar13}
\nomenclature[]{FOO14}{bar14}
\nomenclature[]{FOO15}{bar15}
\nomenclature[]{FOO16}{bar16}
\nomenclature[]{FOO17}{bar17}
\nomenclature[]{FOO18}{bar18}
\nomenclature[]{FOO19}{bar19}
\nomenclature[]{FOO20}{bar20}
\nomenclature[]{FOO21}{bar21}
\nomenclature[]{FOO22}{bar22}
\nomenclature[]{FOO23}{bar23}
\nomenclature[]{FOO24}{bar24}
\nomenclature[]{FOO25}{bar25}
\nomenclature[]{FOO26}{bar26}
\nomenclature[]{FOO27}{bar27}
\nomenclature[]{FOO28}{bar28}
\nomenclature[]{FOO29}{bar29}
\nomenclature[]{FOO30}{bar30}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing an MWE that includes nomenclatures. For my own interest I modified it to use my proposal. It seems that both of our answers work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell `nomencl` does not set any font size, just uses the size set for the main document. I suspect you are using something like `\documentclass[12pt,...]{...}`. It would have been most helpful if you had provided an MWE and I'm not prepared to try and create one. --- GOM

Try something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\begin{document}
% lots of stuff
\begin{small}  % set font to small size
\printnomenclature
\end{small}    % end of small sized fonts
% more stuff?
\enddocument
```